# Print clipping (TextField) occuring during NSPrintOperation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, printing, interface-builder

Does anyone know how to force an application to wrap the text so it will fit on a printed page? I have a resizable text field in a scroll view and if the user resizes it past a certain width, the print preview just cuts the text to the right completely off. Here's my code on .m:

```
    - (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps error:(NSError **)e;
{
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [self printInfo];
    NSPrintOperation *printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:myView
                                                               printInfo:printInfo];
    return printOp;
}
```

then i just specified 'myView' in IB as my scrollview. Anything i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the documentation of the object you're using? NSPrintInfo is configurable. Further, scroll views don't wrap text. Only text views and text fields. Asking a scroll view to print is a bit strange as well. You're askin' the wrong guy, in other words. :-)

Comment: Err, oops. Auto-corrected "askin'" to "admin". That makes no sense. ;-)

Comment: If you don't need the ref to your scroll view, then sure, that would help. Also look into the print operation object to see if it's set the way you want. You'll need to turn on word wrapping (multi-line) in the text field too as "what you see is what you get" when printing.

Comment: Alternatively, you can render your text in an off-screen text view sized and configured as you wish, then print that. That's what people usually do to avoid the inherent problems of directly printing on-screen stuff (as you've run into).

Comment: Josh - i tried attaching the myView to several objects on the page (including the text field) and it still cuts the words off...

Comment: how do i configure word wrapping? I have the text view selected and under attributes inspector there is no option for that : /

Comment: i like the idea of off screen view. How would i do that?? How could i make a view that isn't on the document window?

Comment: NSTextField or NSTextView? Text *fields* need their multi-line option checked. Best to use an NSTextView for printing. For off-screen NSTextView, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/Tasks/AssembleSysByHand.html and just don't add it to any window, releasing the whole assembly when you're done.

Comment: Its a textVIEW. still no cigar : / i'll try the method you suggested, do i skip lines 3 & 4? (of the NSTextView code section on the documentation)

Comment: (i really appreciate the patience Josh thanks, I'm new to this) ok I posted my print method above in the question (this comment won't keep the formatting of the code).  But I also created an IBOutlet in .h for myView - then drug the connector in Files Owner to a resizable textView. I've recreated the issue in a new doc as well. Resizing that particular textView to a certain width just cuts off the text (doesn't wrap it at all)

Comment: Well ... no, because you didn't take my suggestion to create the text view off-screen and to try customizing the NSPrintInfo object you get. :-)

Comment: Maybe it's a clarity issue? When I say "off-screen", I don't mean to do it with Interface Builder. I mean to create it entirely in code as in the examples given in the documentation I linked to. I realize that might not've been clear if you're new to Cocoa. Printing isn't necessarily a straightforward operation when you've got pages of marginalized text, etc.

Comment: i'll give that a shot  - yeah im new to this so it's a bit confusing

Comment: The best way to learn is to break the problem down into parts and attack each one. The parts you need to learn are a) how to create and manipulate an off-screen text view and b) how to customize the NSPrintInfo object to print the way you want. This cocoadev.com wiki page might help: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTextViewPrinting